# I am having problem in my variable "p. Can someone help me?

Tags: python, undefined

```python
import random


def question1():
        print("What is the Capital of Bangladesh?")
        print("Your options are: 1)Dhaka 2)Cumilla 3)Rangpur 4)Barishal")
        # p is answer
        p = 1

def question2():
    print("Where is Bangladesh?")
    print("Your options are: 1)in Africa 2)in Asia 3)in Europe 4)in Antertica")
    # p is answer
    p = 2


n= 1
e= 5000
x= ["a","b"]

while (n==1):
    w= random.randint(0,1)
    y= x[w]
    
    if "a" in y:
        question1()
        l= int(input("Type your option number:"))
        x.remove(y)
        
        if (p == l):
            e=e*2
            print("Congrats!You have won" + e)
        else:
            print("You heve lost!")
            print("You answered" + "answers!")
            n=n+1
        
    elif "b" in y:
        question2()
        l= int(input("Type your option number:"))
        x.remove(y)
        
        if (p == 2):
            e=e*2
            print("Congrats!You have won" + e)
        else:
            print("You heve lost!")
            print("You answered" + "answers!")
            n=n+1

            
print("Your total point is:" + e)
```

I defined "p" variable as the answer of the MCQ questions calling a function. But inside the loop, when I call the function, the "p" variable still stays undefined. I had run that function in the loop in if statement but it seems still undefined. Why is it happening? And how to fix it?

Comment: `p` is a local variable in both functions.  When the function ends, the variable goes away.  What you need to do is have both functions end with return statements (`return 1` or `return 2`), then do `p = question1()` to get the value.

Comment: You can use `y = random.choice(x)` to pick one, and you don't need `if "a" in y:`, just do `if y == "a":`.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a version of your code that works.  You had several problems.  For example, this doesn't work because `e` is an integer, and you can't add strings and integers.

```
           print("Congrats!You have won" + e)
```

Note that I have eliminated the `["a","b"]` nonsense, and have simply created a list with the question functions.  Now I can choose one at random and call it, so I don't have to have a bunch of duplicated code.  One chunk of code handles all the questions.

```
import random

def question1():
    print("What is the Capital of Bangladesh?")
    print("Your options are: 1)Dhaka 2)Cumilla 3)Rangpur 4)Barishal")
    # p is answer
    return 1

def question2():
    print("Where is Bangladesh?")
    print("Your options are: 1)in Africa 2)in Asia 3)in Europe 4)in Antertica")
    # p is answer
    return 2

n= 0
e= 5000
questions = [question1, question2]

while questions:
    question = random.choice(questions)
    answer = question()

    l= int(input("Type your option number:"))
        
    if answer == l:
        questions.remove( question )
        n += 1
        e *= 2
        print("Congrats!You have won", e)
    else:
        print("You heve lost!")
        print("You answered", n,  "answers!")
        break
    
print("Your total point is:", e)
```

Answer (score 1):

'p' is a local variable. It lives inside the function (question1 or 2), but "deleted" once the function ends. You might want your functions to return the value of 'p' and then use it:

```py
import random


def question1():
        print("What is the Capital of Bangladesh?")
        print("Your options are: 1)Dhaka 2)Cumilla 3)Rangpur 4)Barishal")
        # p is answer
        p = 1
        return p

def question2():
    print("Where is Bangladesh?")
    print("Your options are: 1)in Africa 2)in Asia 3)in Europe 4)in Antertica")
    # p is answer
    p = 2
    return p


n= 1
e= 5000
x= ["a","b"]

while (n==1):
    w= random.randint(0,1)
    y= x[w]
    
    if "a" in y:
        p=question1()
        l= int(input("Type your option number:"))
        x.remove(y)
        
        if (p == l):
            e=e*2
            print("Congrats!You have won" + e)
        else:
            print("You heve lost!")
            print("You answered" + "answers!")
            n=n+1
        
    elif "b" in y:
        p=question2()
        l= int(input("Type your option number:"))
        x.remove(y)
        
        if (p == 2):
            e=e*2
            print("Congrats!You have won" + e)
        else:
            print("You heve lost!")
            print("You answered" + "answers!")
            n=n+1

            
print("Your total point is:" + e)
```

(Notice the name of the variable outside doesn't have to be 'p', it can be different from the variable inside the function. I used the same name for your convenience)

Answer (score 0):

You have at least three issues in this code, p not being defined, trying to concatenate a str and an int, and an index error.

To fix the issue of p not being defined declare it as a global variable, or return it from the function. Here's an example of the latter,

```
import random


def question1():
        print("What is the Capital of Bangladesh?")
        print("Your options are: 1)Dhaka 2)Cumilla 3)Rangpur 4)Barishal")
        # p is answer
        return 1

def question2():
    print("Where is Bangladesh?")
    print("Your options are: 1)in Africa 2)in Asia 3)in Europe 4)in Antertica")
    # p is answer
    return 2


n= 1
e= 5000
x= ["a","b"]

while (n==1):
    w= random.randint(0,1)
    y= x[w]
    
    if "a" in y:
        p = question1()
        l= int(input("Type your option number:"))
        x.remove(y)
        
        if (p == l):
            e=e*2
            print("Congrats!You have won" + e)
        else:
            print("You heve lost!")
            print("You answered" + "answers!")
            n=n+1
        
    elif "b" in y:
        p = question2()
        l= int(input("Type your option number:"))
        x.remove(y)
        
        if (p == 2):
            e=e*2
            print("Congrats!You have won" + e)
        else:
            print("You heve lost!")
            print("You answered" + "answers!")
            n=n+1

            
print("Your total point is:" + e)
```

To fix the concatenation error replace e with str(e), for example,

```
print("Your total point is:" + str(e))
```

For the index error, you'll have to look into that yourself, I didn't dive deep enough to help with that. Hope this works for you.

DB

Answer (score -1):

A naive (but simple) solution would be to use the keyword global to make the variable a global variable.

```
def question():
    global p
    p = 1

question()
print(p)
```

But generally you should avoid that as it makes your code very messy and more difficult to predict.

Comment: Clearly the OP is a Python newbie, and starting them with bad advice is only going to land them in more hot water. You say yourself that global is bad, so, why show it then?

Comment: You don't have to write good code at the start. It is just important that you keep going, right? And sometimes an easy fix is all you need. I also think this answer helps underline the difference between local and global scope.